# emitting a message to node.js after page close

Tags: javascript, node.js, events, socket.io, onbeforeunload

So I'm pretty new to it, so I apologize if I this is an entirely wrong approach of doing this, but I am currently programming a little chat application using node.js with express and socket.io. I managed to get a login message logged to the console but I am really struggling with the logout one. When a user opens up the page I take the roomname aswell as the username out of a cookie and send it to the server like shown here:

```
var socket = io();
var roomname = readCookie('Roomname');
var nickname = readCookie('Nickname');
var data = {'type': 'user', 'channel': roomname, 'user': nickname, 'data': "joined"};

socket.emit('chat', data);
```

After that I filter the message on the server side and send the answer to all clients like this:

```
case 'user':
  io.emit('chat/' + msg.channel, {type: 'user', user: msg.user, data: msg.data});
  break;
```

I always send the string "chat" followed by the roomname as a channel name so only the users that are in the right rooms can see the message. After that I sort out what kind of message was received by the client side:

```
case 'user':
  console.log(msg.user + " just " + msg.data + " the room!");
  break;
```

Now the only thing I need to do is somehow getting the room- and username to the server side once the user closes the page so I can send the message but with "left". (like this)

```
var data = {'type': 'user', 'channel': roomname, 'user': nickname, 'data': "left"};

socket.emit('chat', data);
```

My approach was finding an event that fires the code at the right time and I have been looking through stack overflow for a good hour now and I just couldn't find anything that did the job. I've tryed out all the variations of `window.onbeforeunload` I could find and none of them seemed to work. I could log some stuff to the console with some of them but I was never able to emit a message to the server side. I am aware that this may not be possible in the way I would like it to, but I really ran out of ideas what to try next. Can someone help me out?

Comment: You cannot reliably know when a client has disappeared. The right way to do this is with a timeout system.

Comment: @Pointy That is very sad! Because I can do just that on the server side using
`socket.on('disconnect', myFunction();)`
my matter is just that like that I don't have any username to display if I was to use this. So if I got it right you reccomend me to emit and check a kind of "Hey, I'm still here" Message every few seconds to detect when the user left? Right?

Comment: Yes, something like that, or just a simple timer that you reset every time you get an actual message from the user. If you think about it, the user closing the browser tab or turning off the computer isn't much different from the user just standing up and going out to dinner.

Comment: It really really bugs me because it will either unnecessarily increase the traffic between client and server or it won't be accurate at all.. :/ But if it is the only choice I guess I'll have to do it that way. If you are sure there is no other way please add this as an answer so I can accept it. Thank you for taking the time to help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add information about the client's username to the socket object, when the client connects for the first time. Then you will be able to use socket.username when client disconnects.

Client:

```
var socket = io();
var roomname = readCookie('Roomname');
var nickname = readCookie('Nickname');
socket.on('connect', () => {
    socket.emit("hello", {nick:nickname, room:roomname});
});
```

Server:

```
socket.on("hello", (data) => {
    socket.username = data.nick;
    socket.join(data.room);
    socket.room = data.room;
});
socket.on("disconnect", () => {
    var data = {'type':'user', 'channel':socket.room, 'user':socket.username, 'data':'left'};
    socket.broadcast.to(socket.room).emit('chat', data};
    socket.leave(socket.room);
});
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was searching for! I just started to try and build a user variable on my own but I knew there had to be some other way! I will try it out and tell you the result asap! Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: This is certainly useful, though if the user just turns off their phone or computer you won't get that "disconnect" event.

Comment: Of course I will. The "disconnect" event is fired at the server side not received from the client.

Comment: @mk12ok ah OK, sorry; that makes sense.

Comment: Man you simultaneously fixed my problem aswell as overall improved my code! It worked just as I wantet it to. I was so dumb.. I always wondered why there are no channels and why I had to tinker. I used to just add the roomname after 'chat/' so it always only gets the messages from for example 'chat/room_1'. You killed two birds with one stone. Thank you so much!! :D